# What does "unload class" mean?

Tags: java, android, static

While looking when a static variable of a class does not exist anymore, I've found that when a class is unloaded, their static variables are reinitialised. Is "unload class" means destroy (if we suppose that this class is an activity) ?
Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unloading class may or may not occure, depending on the JVM implementation and should not affect any class which classloader is accessible. Citation from JLS:

> A class or interface may be unloaded if and only if its defining class loader may be reclaimed by the garbage collector as discussed"

A fully description which might/might not happen you can find in the ´[Java language specification #12.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.7).

Answer (score -1):

Unload class id done by classloader if it requires memory to load new classes and not enough memory is available.

When it happens if the unloaded class is reloaded in a different moment the static variables are reinitialized.

Comment: Based on the JLS I would argue that the classloader is **not** responsible for the unloading `A class or interface may be unloaded if and only if its defining class loader may be reclaimed by the garbage collector as discussed`. [JLS 12.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.7)

Comment: @SubOptimal that's true, I'd make it an answer.

Comment: @weston See my answer from today at around 14:00.